# Why Selenium webdriver with Python can't reach to a website

Tags: python, selenium

I am trying to use selenium with chrome driver to connect to a website. But it couldn't be reached.
Here is my code:

```
    from selenium import webdriver
    from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
    
    CHROME_EXECUTABLE_PATH = "C://Program Files (x86)//Chrome Driver//chromedriver.exe"
    CHROME_OPTIONS = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
    CHROME_OPTIONS.add_argument("--disable-notifications")
    BASE_URL = "https://www.nordstrom.com/"
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=CHROME_EXECUTABLE_PATH, options=CHROME_OPTIONS)
    # locators
    search_button_locator = "//a[@id='controls-keyword-search-popover']"
    search_box_locator = "//*[@id='keyword-search-input']"
    
    driver.get(BASE_URL)
    driver.find_element(By.XPATH, search_button_locator)
    driver.find_element(By.XPATH, search_box_locator).send_keys("Fave Slipper")
```

This code gives me some error:

```
E:\Python\Nordstrom.com\venv\Scripts\python.exe E:/Python/Nordstrom.com/pages/simple.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "E:\Python\Nordstrom.com\pages\simple.py", line 14, in <module>
    driver.find_element(By.XPATH, search_button_locator)
  File "E:\Python\Nordstrom.com\venv\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 976, in find_element
    return self.execute(Command.FIND_ELEMENT, {
  File "E:\Python\Nordstrom.com\venv\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 321, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "E:\Python\Nordstrom.com\venv\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\errorhandler.py", line 242, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//a[@id='controls-keyword-search-popover']"}
  (Session info: chrome=94.0.4606.61)


Process finished with exit code 1
```

The page looks like this:

[image: Founded page]

But the expected page should be looks like this:

[image: Expected page]

How to access this website?

Comment: You appear to be connecting to the site successfully, however your XPATH isn't finding what you were hoping to see

Comment: I could not reach the home page. How could I find the elements I am looking for? My question is why I could not reach to the home page?

Comment: The website is directly saying `To keep our site secure, we don’t allow unidentified, automated traffic. If you’d like access to our data via automation, apply to join the Nordstrom Affiliate Network!` - that means you should not scrape them at all.

Answer (score 2):

The error points out that it was unable to find the XPATH element, which is why it errored out.

The main causes for this can be either:

- the XPATH is wrong
- the element has not loaded yet on the page
- the site has detected your scraping attempt and blocked you

In this case it's a combination of the 2nd and 3rd options. Whenever you use a webdriver, it exposes javascript hooks that websites can detect. To hide your activity you should learn more on how [device fingerprinting](https://staffordwilliams.com/blog/2020/07/08/browser-fingerprinting-concealing-selenium/) and either customize your script to hide itself or use a pre-made solution for it (such as PhantomJS).

Most likely you should also look into hiding your IP by using a proxy.

Comment: This answer is misleading, the website says `To keep our site secure, we don’t allow unidentified, automated traffic. If you’d like access to our data via automation, apply to join the Nordstrom Affiliate Network!`

Comment: The XPATH is not wrong. How do the elements load as I couldn't reach the home page? The problem is I can't reach the page. This is because they don't allow automation. One thing more, as you said hiding my IP using a proxy. How to do that?

Comment: What should be the proxy?

Comment: Mostly high-quality residential proxies should be fine. Yes, the xpath is correct but the site is detecting your webdriver through some fingerprinting method.

Comment: What should be the proxy? I have no idea about high-quality residential proxies. Is it something like 177.202.59.58? Where could I find the proxy I should use?

Answer (score 0):

There is a problem with your 'BASE_URL' so try another Browser to debug the issue and also try to use explicit wait before click or locate any element